# Fan Gate and Liking an App

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like

I'm trying to figure out how to do something, and I've tried searching Stack Overflow, but I'm honestly not 100% sure what I'm looking for, so I'm not coming up with anything great.

Here is what I need to do:

We have an app, and you're supposed to like the page to see the app.  Great that works.

The client wants us to put a facebook share button on the site, so that when you're finished using the app, you can click the "Share" button and post something to your wall saying, "I just used XXX and you should too!" or whatever.  The problem is that the Share button is deprecated.  Everything on the facebook developer site says I need to use the like button, but, since you've already LIKED the page to get in, you're going to see that you've already liked the page and not be allowed to click it again to share content on your news feed.

It seems like I'm missing something here.  Can you have a like button for a page AND a specific app inside that fan page?  It doesn't seem like I can do that.  Is what I'm asking even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Javascript SDK to post to the wall... this uses jQuery to detect a click on an id which is the share button so make sure you add this before any facebook javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You will also need to load the FB Javascript SDK if you haven't already:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'INSERT APP ID',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });


    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
            ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Then add the following code:

```
  $("#shareclick").click(function () {

      FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'The Post Title',
          caption: 'skruffymedia testing caption post',
          description: (
              'Testing the description of the skruffymedia app post!'),
          link: 'http://www.skruffymedia.com',
          picture: 'http://www.skruffymedia.com/facebook.jpg'
      }, function (response) {
          if (response && response.post_id) {
              alert('posted');
          } else {
              alert('not shared');
          }
      });

  }); //End Share Click
```

I'll be including this answer on the next step of my blog 
http://www.skruffymedia.com/blog/creating-a-facebook-like-gate-competition/

Answer (score 0):

It is now against Facebook's policies to gate an app or content within an app based on if someone has liked your page.

See the announcement here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/